# array formula in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am creating a source parse for work. I am using the formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(iferror(split(B2:B,"&fbclid",false,true),"Unknown"))
```

Sometimes a source will come in with the URL parameter blank which is labeled as Unknown. The issue I am having is that the rows below the data are also rendered as unknown. Each day I will be adding more leads to be parsed, but how do I only show unknown for leads that are being parsed and not for the rows that have nothing at all.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(iferror(if(B2:B="",,split(B2:B,"&fbclid",false,true),"Unknown")))
```